# My backgrounds planes get distorted in the render

Tags: rendering

The figures are two parent planes, everything looks good in render mode, object mode, and all other modes, but when I render the image the background planes bend strangely.

This didn't happen before so I'm sure I accidentally pressed something, Iam still a beginner, thank you.[image]

Comment: Is it possible those bg planes have a subdivision modifier, set to 0 in preview but something else in render?

Comment: if Nathans answer does not help - please provide your blend file

Comment: @Nathan was right. The modifier was set to 0 in view and 3 in render, Thank you guys!